# How to compare versions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How to write a piece of code to compare some versions strings and get the newest?

For example strings like: `'0.1', '0.2.1', '0.44'`.

Comment: I needed to compare pessimistic version constraints a while back, but I didn't want to depend on RubyGems to do it, so I wrote a simple `Version` class that does everything I need: http://shorts.jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2014/compare-version-numbers-with-pessimistic-constraints/

Answer (score 266):

```
Gem::Version.new('0.4.1') > Gem::Version.new('0.10.1')
```

Comment: The `Gem::Version...` syntax made me thought I would need to install a gem. But it was not required.

Comment: Note: This gives an error about undefined variable 'Gem' for me on Ruby 1.x, but works as expected on Ruby 2.x. In my case I was checking RUBY_VERSION against being Ruby 1.x (not 2.x), so I just did RUBY_VERSION.split('.')[0] == "1" like John Hyland and DigitalRoss do it.

Comment: `Gem::Dependency.new(nil, '~> 1.4.5').match?(nil, '1.4.6beta4')`

Comment: @uliwitness it's not Ruby 1.x vs 2.x; it's 1.8.x vs 1.9+. Ruby through 1.8.x doesn't include rubygems by default; you need a `require 'rubygems'` to get access to the `Gem` namespace. From 1.9 on, however, it's automatically included.

Comment: This worked for comparing wildcard NPM versions too. +1

Comment: Although discouraged, this handles `nil` versions quite nicely as well. :+1:

Answer (score 43):

If you need to check [pessimistic version constraints](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16), you can use [Gem::Dependency](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Dependency.html) like this:

```
Gem::Dependency.new('', '~> 1.4.5').match?('', '1.4.6beta4')
```

Comment: Newer versions appear to require a string for the name. An empty string works fine, i.e. `Gem::Dependency.new('', '~> 1.4.5').match?('', '1.4.6beta4')`

Answer (score 22):

```
class Version < Array
  def initialize s
    super(s.split('.').map { |e| e.to_i })
  end
  def < x
    (self <=> x) < 0
  end
  def > x
    (self <=> x) > 0
  end
  def == x
    (self <=> x) == 0
  end
end
p [Version.new('1.2') < Version.new('1.2.1')]
p [Version.new('1.2') < Version.new('1.10.1')]
```

Comment: Like some of the other answers here, it looks like you're doing string comparisons instead of numerical, which will cause problems when comparing versions like '0.10' and '0.4'.

Comment: Upvoted for concise solution which does not require installing a gem.

Comment: For what it's worth:

`vers = (1..3000000).map{|x| "0.0.#{x}"}; 'ok'
puts Time.now; vers.map{|v| ComparableVersion.new(v) }.sort.first; puts Time.now

# 24 seconds
2013-10-29 13:36:09 -0700
2013-10-29 13:36:33 -0700
 => nil

puts Time.now; vers.map{|v| Gem::Version.new(v) }.sort.first; puts Time.now

# 41 seconds
2013-10-29 13:36:53 -0700
2013-10-29 13:37:34 -0700`

Code blob is making it ugly, but basically, using this vs Gem::Version is about twice as faster.

Comment: A version is __not__ an array, though.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [`Versionomy` gem](http://github.com/dazuma/versionomy) (available at [github](http://github.com/dazuma/versionomy)):

```
require 'versionomy'

v1 = Versionomy.parse('0.1')
v2 = Versionomy.parse('0.2.1')
v3 = Versionomy.parse('0.44')

v1 < v2  # => true
v2 < v3  # => true

v1 > v2  # => false
v2 > v3  # => false
```

Comment: I have seen that, but require me to use 2 gems to do a really simple thing. I want to use that as last choice.

Comment: "Don't reinvent the wheel". Because it's simple doesn't mean the programmer didn't put work and thought into it. Use the gem, read the code, and learn from it - and move on to bigger and better things!

Comment: Dependency management and version maintenance is a difficult problem, probably much more difficult than the task of comparing 2 versions. I totally agree that introducing 2 more dependencies should be a last resort in this case.

Answer (score 11):

I would do

```
a1 = v1.split('.').map{|s|s.to_i}
a2 = v2.split('.').map{|s|s.to_i}
```

Then you can do

```
a1 <=> a2
```

<s>(and probably all the other "usual" comparisons).</s>

...and if you want a `<` or `>` test, you can do e.g.

```
(a1 <=> a2) < 0
```

or do some more function wrapping if you're so inclined.

Comment: Array.class_eval {include Comparable} will make all arrays respond to <, >, etc.  Or, if you just want to do this to certain arrays: a = [1, 2]; a.extend(Comparable)

Comment: The problem I found with this solution is that it returns that "1.2.0" is bigger than "1.2"

Answer (score 9):

`Gem::Version` is the easy way to go here:

```
%w<0.1 0.2.1 0.44>.map {|v| Gem::Version.new v}.max.to_s
=> "0.44"
```

Comment: Much better than versionomy which requires a c-extension!?

Comment: i don't think 'max' will work.. it will report 0.5 to be greater than 0.44. Which is not true when comparing semver versions.

Comment: this seems to have been fixed in latest Gem::Version. 0.44 is correctly reported as higher than 0.5 now.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it by hand without using any gems, something like the following should work, though it's a little perly looking.

```
versions = [ '0.10', '0.2.1', '0.4' ]
versions.map{ |v| (v.split '.').collect(&:to_i) }.max.join '.'
```

Essentially, you turn each version string in to an array of integers and then use the [array comparison operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002204).  You could break out the component steps to get something a little easier to follow if this is going in code somebody will need to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I wanted a Gem-less version comparator, came up with this:

```ruby
def compare_versions(versionString1,versionString2)
    v1 = versionString1.split('.').collect(&:to_i)
    v2 = versionString2.split('.').collect(&:to_i)
    #pad with zeroes so they're the same length
    while v1.length < v2.length
        v1.push(0)
    end
    while v2.length < v1.length
        v2.push(0)
    end
    for pair in v1.zip(v2)
        diff = pair[0] - pair[1]
        return diff if diff != 0
    end
    return 0
end
```