# How can I sort an array of strings with numbers like "2.1.2.5"?

Tags: ruby, string, integer

I have an array of strings:

```
arr = ["2.1", "2.2", "2.2.1", "2.2.10", "2.2.2", "2.10"]
```

If I use `arr.sort`, the result is:

```
["2.1", "2.10", "2.2", "2.2.1", "2.2.10", "2.2.2"]
```

I need:

```
["2.1", "2.2", "2.2.1", "2.2.2", "2.2.10", "2.10"]
```

How can I sort it correctly?

**Question 2:**

How can I sort "alpha" or "beta"-type characters like "2.1a" or "0.9b"

**Question 3:**

If I have an array of active records with field type of string, which contains number like that, is it real to set in model `default_scope :order => ...` with `sort_by{|a| a.split('.').map &:to_i }`

*Or*

Create my method in model something like

```
def my_sort
  #sorting
end
```

For this:

```
Block.all.my_sort
```

Comment: looks like you need to compare versio numbers, like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051229/how-to-compare-versions-in-ruby

Comment: Is there a chance that any "alpha" or "beta"-type characters, ('2.1a' or '0.9b') are going to be encountered?

Comment: yes, there is a chance. Thank you, I forgot about it, I can face this problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr.sort_by{|a| a.split('.').map &:to_i }
```

Which will:

1. `split` each of the strings into components.
2. Change each of them into integers (`map &:to_i`).
3. Compare between each other these arrays.

Comment: And what if I have an array of active records with field type of string contains number like that, is it real to do `default_scope :order => ...` with `sort_by{|a| a.split('.').map &:to_i }`?