# Correct way to test Rails version for gem authoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

What is the correct way to manage conditional flow in a gem based on Rails version?

Rails 4 changes some things so I need to conditionally flow based on Rails major version being 4 vs. 3 or prior.

The closest I've come is:

```
if Rails.version.split(".").first.to_i < 4
    # Do the Rails 4 thing
else 
    # Do it the old way
end
```

Comment: Don't you specify your Rails version in your Gemfile?

Comment: I'm authoring a gem and it needs to support Rails from version 2.x  to 4.x.  Unfortunately, Rails 4 changed one of the core ActiveSupport components (factored out to a gem of its own, actually), so I need to change behavior of the gem for Rails 4 (it still works fine for versions 2.x - 3.x).

Comment: I am not sure if you will be able to do that..My thinking is that once your gem is built, Rubygems will run that code and create a static representation of it...

Comment: The above *works*  I just don't think its the Rails Way to do it.  All I need to do is check at run/load time what the Rails version is so that the gem continues to support each version of Rails appropriately.

Comment: `"4.0.1".to_i` is `4`. You don't need to split if you don't care about anything after the decimal place.

Comment: @Nobita The only thing that's "static" is your `.gemspec` file. All Ruby code within your gem is still live code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rails defines constants under `Rails::VERSION` for the various patch levels: `MAJOR`, `MINOR`, `TINY` and `PRE` (if applicable). The version string is [constructed from these integers](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f3982858359008ec8fe43b8fa2c75aad8788cd89/version.rb#L8), and you can use them directly:

```
if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 4
  # Do the new thing
else
  # Do it the old way
end
```

These go back [to at least Rails 2.0.x](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/81d828a14c82b882e31612431a56f830bdc1076f/railties/lib/rails/version.rb) so they should be safe to use for your gem's permitted dependency spec.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think `Rails.version =~ /^4/` reads much better.

Comment: `Rails.version.to_i >= 4` is also an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Safest simple way is to use for example

```rb
Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) >= Gem::Version.new('5.1')
```

Unless you really need to only compare the major version.

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3064161/520567