# Check ruby version to puts message

Tags: ruby

I am trying to test if the user has a Ruby version greater than or equal to 1.9.0, and if not, update it.

```
output = `ruby -v`
if !output ~> "1.9.0"
```

But as I read, if the version is 1.8.7, then it would say that it is above 1.9.0 since `~>` means that the version is approximately greater than the last digit.

---

Correction to the original question , the `~>` is not valid, was a misinterpretation to a gem specific thing I read.

Comment: I didn't even know there was an `~>` operator. In any case, split the string apart and compare each segment as a number.

Comment: well I'm new to ruby, is there a one liner here that would work?

Comment: You can check my edited answer below for an easy example.

Comment: @DaveNewton Looks like `~>` is syntactically invalid. So there probably isn't. The OP must have mistaken something.

Comment: @sawa why? `! ~ + - Not, complement, unary plus and minus (method names for the last two are +@ and -@) ` IE ~> right?

Comment: @sawa this is where I got that anyways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170547/what-does-tilde-greater-than-mean-in-ruby-gem-dependencies

Comment: A Ruby method is defined on objects. `>` is not an object.

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC Gemfile version specifiers are strings, not Ruby code.

Comment: @DaveNewton fair enough.  Don't get why needed to know if the ruby version is at a min level is worth down voting and closing though...

Comment: I don't know, but I'd guess because people assumed you'd actually tried the code you posted, it's fairly easy to search for, and fairly easy to solve via code. I think it's very clear what you're asking, so I don't get the reason everyone chose for closing.

Comment: @DaveNewton true and all but I see SO as the place to find the best solution. see everyone did the just code it approach and failed to produce what was the best answer as of yet, a simple `if Gem::Version.new('0.4.1') > Gem::Version.new('0.10.1')` ... that is why I'm sadden but worth the negative to find that gem ... :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare versions in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051229/how-to-compare-versions-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few gems available for this.

[Versionomy](https://rubygems.org/gems/versionomy) is probably the most popular. You'll use something like this:

```
require 'versionomy'

v1 = Versionomy.parse('0.1')
v2 = Versionomy.parse('0.2.1')
v3 = Versionomy.parse('0.44')

v1 < v2  # => true
v2 < v3  # => true

v1 > v2  # => false
v2 > v3  # => false
```

Also note that there's a top level constant `RUBY_VERSION` you can use the get the Ruby version within rails.

Edit: If you simply want to check the second digit you can use:

```
version = RUBY_VERSION.split(".")[1]
```

This will return '9' for 1.9.2.

Comment: well dang that would mean that I need to force install another gem right? looking for something very simple and light just to push the user to update as I'd think I can't update ruby from ruby so I just need to prompt them

Comment: Well you can also split the version string and compare the numbers.

Comment: so, sorry didn't notice that it had the rail tag in the question, not using ruby on rails, just ruby and tasks

Comment: This works without rails as well. It's a top level constant of the Ruby language.

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC If your version requirements are *very* simple you could compare strings, although personally that'd sketch me out a little. Otherwise it's just iterate-over-the-chunks-and-compare.

Comment: @Chris911 Checking the second digit is going to fail for Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: @tadman in the end what I did was  `       ver_array=RUBY_VERSION.split(".")
        version = ver_array[0]
        subversion = ver_array[1]
        if (version.to_i >= 1 && subversion.to_i > 8) || (version.to_i == 2 )`

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC That's going to blow up in a huge way when Ruby 3.0 hits. I'd be very hesitant to deploy code like that. Using [one of these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051229/how-to-compare-versions-in-ruby) would be a *lot* better. As an example, `Gem::Version` is built-in, so you have no excuse not to use it. `Gem::Dependency` even supports the `~>` operator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3064161/746758 is a wonderful answer.. that is exactly what I was looking for.  sad part is that all I needed what to have Googled compare ruby versions.. thank you for pointing that one out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strings

```
RUBY_VERSION < '1.9.0'
```

Comment: so, sorry didn't notice that it had the rail tag in the question, not using ruby on rails, just ruby and tasks

Comment: Since there's no Ruby 1.10 this works.